# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sql_regcase

Tags: php, mysql, web

**Can somebody help me with these**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sql_regcase() in /home/vol13_5/byethost24.com/b24_19881615/htdocs/core.php:157 Stack trace: #0 /home/vol13_5/byethost24.com/b24_19881615/htdocs/core/pages/signup.php(6): text_filter('', 1) #1 {main} thrown in /home/vol13_5/byethost24.com/b24_19881615/htdocs/core.php on line 157

line 157 is:

```
$text = preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(drop table|show tables|#|--|\\\\)/"),"",$text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be you are using **php7** or higher in which `sql-regcase` is **removed**

[Reference of sql-regcase](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sql-regcase.php)

Answer (score 1):

This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0 - are you using PHP7 (use php --version to know)
If not using PHP7 but an older release, did you enable the mysql extension in your php.ini file?

Note that use of mysql_* function is deprecated as well, so use pdo or mysqli